# Pandas time series merge: result longer than components

Tags: python, r, merge, pandas, xts

I have got a peculiar question about merging/aligning two millisec-based times series in pandas. I have:

- ts1 with Name: SOME_NAME, Length: 2863, dtype: int64
- ts2 with Name: SOME_OTHER_NAME, Length: 22992, dtype: int64
- type(ts1): < class 'pandas.core.series.TimeSeries' >
- type(ts2): < class 'pandas.core.series.TimeSeries' >
- ts1.index: < class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex' >
  [2010-01-01 11:15:05.933000, ..., 2010-01-01 11:25:48.073000]
  Length: 2863, Freq: None, Timezone: None
- ts2.index: < class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex' >
  [2010-01-01 11:15:00.564000, ..., 2013-01-01 11:25:59.824000]
  Length: 22992, Freq: None, Timezone: None

I have been doing the following:

- ts3 = ts2.align(ts1, join='outer')

The result is:

- tuple ts3 with Name: SOME_OTHER_NAME, Length: 28345, dtype: float64, ..., Name: SOME_NAME, Length: 28345, dtype: float64)

Maybe I am missing something, but how can an outer merge/align ever yield more data points than the two constituents together? For sure 22992 + 2863 < 28345!
Very puzzled. Has anybody come across this sort of result?
Thanks!

Comment: I tried reproducing this issue on made-up data, and everything worked as expected. Can you reproduce this with a smaller data set and demonstrate? (Maybe try using progressively smaller sections of your original data set and see if the error persists.) Also, which version of pandas? I'm not aware of a bug in this area, but maybe someone else is.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I have now managed to find the source of the above behavior by isolating the parts of the dataset that produce the "excess data" upon doing the outer merge. As it turns out (and is actually documented for Pandas - my bad here), the outer merge produces a Cartesian product for data points with the same index value (in my case the same ms timestamp). That means that for, say, 2 datapoints in ts1 and 4 in ts2 with the same time index, the result is 8 merged datapoints. This contracts with merge.xts in R which I have used a lot in the past where the result would be 6.